# how to set days of the week using sqlite

Tags: c++, sql, qt, sqlite

I have created table with Employee, and I have columns such as Name, WorkingDays (datatype is date). I want to write a query that will output something like
 "select Name from Employee where WorkingDay = 'monday', 'wednesday' and 'friday' "
i.e..I want to make a roaster for the workers. I am using sqlite and QT. thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.  Showing effort will get you results on SO, and thus far, you haven't shown any.

Comment: And give more details about your schema, especially the data type of WorkingDays.

Comment: Hi thanks for the responds. have actually been going through the sqlite documentation [http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html] and I know if u write a query like 'select strftime('%w', '2013-11-14')'it gives the day of the week. but the problem is how to get like 3days. First of all I would like to know if it is possible? thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Date And Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) documentation, you can use `strftime` function in this way:

```
SELECT Name FROM Employee WHERE strftime('%w',WorkingDay) IN ('1','3','5');
```

Where `('1','3','5')` are `('Monday', 'Wednesday', 'Friday')` respectively.

---

An off-topic note:

> WorkingDays (datatype is date)

There's no such thing in SQLite. From [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) documentation:

> **1.2 Date and Time Datatype**
>
> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
>   and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
>   are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
>   values:
>
> - TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
> - REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic
>     Gregorian calendar.
> - INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
>
> Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these
>   formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and
>   time functions.

### Update

> so that for example if today is friday, then automatically this name
>   appears on the names working today. Is it possible?

Yes it is. Just need to use `strftime()` function properly. I'll give you a little example:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    name  VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE WorkingDays(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    employee INTEGER, 
    dayNumber INTEGER, 
    FOREIGN KEY(employee) REFERENCES Employee(id),
    UNIQUE(employee,dayNumer)
);

INSERT INTO Employee(name) VALUES('Max');
INSERT INTO Employee(name) VALUES('dic19');
INSERT INTO WorkingDays(employee,dayNumber) VALUES(1,1); --Max, Monday
INSERT INTO WorkingDays(employee,dayNumber) VALUES(1,2); --Max, Tuesday
INSERT INTO WorkingDays(employee,dayNumber) VALUES(1,3); --Max, Wednesday
INSERT INTO WorkingDays(employee,dayNumber) VALUES(2,4); --dic19, Thursday
INSERT INTO WorkingDays(employee,dayNumber) VALUES(2,5); --dic19, Friday
INSERT INTO WorkingDays(employee,dayNumber) VALUES(2,6); --dic19, Saturday

SELECT e.name
FROM  WorkingDays w 
LEFT JOIN  Employee e ON  w.employee = e.id
WHERE cast(w.dayNumber as text) = strftime('%w','now');
-- Right now it should return 'dic19' because Today is Friday/Saturday (depends on time zone)

SELECT e.name 
FROM  WorkingDays w 
LEFT JOIN  Employee e ON  w.employee = e.id 
WHERE cast(w.dayNumber as text) = strftime('%w','2013-11-11');
-- Should return 'Max' because '2013-11-11' was Monday
```

Comment: …thanks dic19 for your reply..I run the query and it gives me the names of those whose working dates falls between these days. I would like to know..how is it possible to say that a particular worker has 'monday', 'wednesday' and 'friday' as his working days. so that for example if today is friday, then automatically this name appears on the names working today. Is it possible?

Comment: Hi there! Yes it is. I'm writing a little example to demonstrate this. But the key is this function: `strftime('%w','now')`. @Max

Comment: …wow this is incredible. i wonder how many days it would have taken me to figure this out …thanks a lot :-)